# unexpected T_STRING with php SimpleImage

Tags: php

I've been using [SimpleImage](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage) locally with PHP5.5 and it works fine, but I've just uploaded to a server running PHP5.4, which SimpleImage supports, and I get:

```
PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

For this line:

```
$img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($url);
```

Full code:

```
include 'images/simple.php';

        try {   
            $img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($url);
            $img->auto_orient()->contrast(-10)->colorize('#ff6600', .05)->brightness(5);
            $img->save($new);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo '<div id="fail">'.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: that's a namespace issue are you sure you are running `5.4` ?

Comment: I changed to 5.3 and then back to 5.4 on the server, and that solved it. Thanks.